# List using subsites as items?

Tags: 2010, list, development

I'm looking for a way of AUTOMATICALLY adding an item to a list on a root-site when you create a new subsite of a specific type.

Context:
I'm building a "Project Portal", and there's a requirement for a dashboard type webpart that displays [ALL], [OPEN] and [CLOSED] projects. Each project has it's own subsite (built from a custom site-template) and also has a status-indicator to show the progress of the project.

The easiest thing I could think of, was a custom list on the root-site, which contained a listitem per project (subsite), with one of the columns being a lookup value to that project's status indicator. That way I could just make views, filtering on that status indicator. But how would I make this list? Is it possible without custom code?

The only way I can think of, is creating an event handler, when a new site is created, check if it's the right template being used (can you even accomplish this?) and then using code create the list item. Is this a solution? and is it the only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose a 3rd route, just wanted to share my final decision, if anyone finds it helpful.

I opted to make a webpart that simply makes use of [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx). This query searches subsites for lists called "Project Status", which is a status list. Alle project/subsites have this list, and have only a single status indicator (Project Status), which the webparts fetches for each of the subsites, and displays them in the webpart.

In order to make the filtering I chose to make a jQuery tabpanel, with three tabs [All], [Open] and [Closed], and each tab contained a simple bullet list of links to the subsites - filtered and fed from the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way without custom code. But what I'd do was:

- Create a web-scoped feature which in the FeatureActivated event in the FeatureReceiver added the item to the list in to Site collection RootWeb
- Make the feature hidden
- Include the feature in the `<WebFeatures>` section of the custom templates onet.xml

Comment: I like that idea - the other answer I got on technet was a list with an added item event handler, that creates the subsite - so you'd essentially be using the list as creation for the projects. I like this better, as it doesn't force users to use the list! Thanks, I'm gonna try to implement it, and mark as answer if it fits :)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed fire an event when a new site is created and check the template ([SPWeb.WebTemplateId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webtemplateid.aspx))

You would make a farm-scoped, webapp-scoped or site-scoped feature and leverage the [WebProvisioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webprovisioned.aspx) event (which triggers every time any web is created on that scope).

It's very much equivalent to Per's method. In fact since you are using a custom site definition I would probably go with the web-scoped feature linked to that definition.

Comment: Thank you! Two good suggestions. I'm gonna test both, and see which fits the profile and the user interactions better.